# Make Writable stream internal write method receive "string" chunk

Tags: node.js

I'm creating a NodeJS Writable instance using the following code (in Typescript)

```
    import { Writable } from 'stream';
    
    
    const writableStream = new Writable({
      write(chunk, encoding, callback) {
        const success = process.stdout.write(chunk);
        console.log(typeof chunk, encoding);
        callback(null);
      }
    });

    writableStream.write('asd', 'utf8');
    writableStream.write('123');
```

It logs out that the type of chunk for both writes is "object" and the encoding is "buffer".

How come it is not "string" and "utf8" which is also said to be a default encoding?
How to make the `chunk` be of type `string` and `encoding` be the encoding given to `writableStream.write`?

(Node v14.15.1)

Comment: Add [`objectMode: true`](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_new_stream_writable_options) to the options object.

Comment: I don't see the point of the encoding then. When you provide a string in non-object mode it is automatically serialized into buffer of bytes. That is when the given encoding should be applied.

Comment: Agreed, you should allow the stream to apply the encoding for you generally speaking, but you're the one that asked the question.